# How to monitor my current position in ARCore and Sceneform?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

In application with ARCore and Sceneform I need somehow monitor my (device, really) movement in ARCore space?

As result I want to draw a ray from selected point (`Anchor`/`AnchorNode`) through my current position, or to calculate distance from selected point to here, and update them during movement. I have ideas, how to calculate or draw, but how to get updates?

Answer (score 3):

First setup an On Update listener

```
fragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addOnUpdateListener(frameTime -> {
        fragment.onUpdate(frameTime);
        onUpdate();
    });
```

In OnUpdate() call Camera.getDisplayOrientedPose()

```
Frame frame = fragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

    Camera camera = frame.getCamera();

    if (camera.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING){
        Pose CameraPose = camera.getDisplayOrientedPose();
    }
```

As you move around your Camera Pose will keep getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

In the [BaseArFragment#onUpdate()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/BaseArFragment#onUpdate(com.google.ar.sceneform.FrameTime)) method you can acquire the [Camera](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Camera) object by calling [ArFragment#getArSceneView()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/BaseArFragment#getArSceneView()), [ArSceneView#getArFrame()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ArSceneView#getArFrame()), and [Frame#getCamera()](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/Frame#getCamera()).

```
override fun onUpdate(frameTime: FrameTime?) {
    super.onUpdate(frameTime)
    doSomething(arSceneView.arFrame?.camera?.pose)
}
```

This `Camera` is a `Node` object that tracks the position of the viewing device, and has a `Pose` object that contains the positional and rotational information you need.